# Have flex children only use space if they need it to not scroll, but otherwise share space equally and scroll

Tags: html, css, scroll, flexbox, overflow

I have two flex children that may either each be small or large, and I'm defining small as < 50% of the container's height and large as > 50% the container's height. The sum of the heights of the children may be larger than 100% of the container's height, in which case I'd want one or both to scroll.

If one child is small and the other is large, I'd like the small element to use exactly the space it needs: it should not shrink to accommodate the large element, nor grow to 50%, and it should not scroll its contents. I'd like the large element to use the rest of the space, and scroll its contents if necessary.

If both are large, I'd like them to each use 50% of the container's height and scroll their contents.

I have this Codepen started as an example to help illustrate what I'm trying to achieve, but unfortunately it currently does no amount of scrolling or resizing: https://codepen.io/joeysilva/pen/wvmPqLK. It has both a small-large and a large-large case.

```css
.flex-container {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.child {
  flex: 50%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.small {
  background: red;
  height: 30px;
}

.large {
  background: blue;
  height: 110px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="small">Small</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="large">Large</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="large">Large 1</div>
    <div class="large">Large 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note 1:** Not use `display:inline-block` and `display:flex` at the same time. Simply add another wrapper to show elements inside a row or column.

**Note 2:** `flex: 50%;` is equivalent to `flex: 1 1 50%;` and this is the shorthand form of `flex-grow: 1; flex-shrink: 1; flex-basis: 50%;`. Here in your code, there's no need to use them because you have strictly defined the height of elements and also the basis of 50% height is wrong since you'd like the small element to use exactly the space it needs; no grow & no shrink, so it should be omitted.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.flex-container {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.child {
  overflow: auto;
}

.small {
  background: red;
  height: 30px;
}

.large {
  background: blue;
  height: 110px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="child">
      <div class="small">Small</div>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      <div class="large">Large</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="child">
      <div class="large">Large 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      <div class="large">Large 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely closer to what I'm looking for! But I don't want the small element to scroll because it's using less than half of the container's height. Is there a way to apply CSS to .child so that small will not scroll but large will?

Comment: It seems disabling shrink on the parent of `small` child is a workaround. `<div class="child" style="flex-shrink:0;">`

Comment: Thanks. I guess the best that can be done here is to have some JS detect if an element is < 50% the total height of the parent and apply flex-shrink:0 to it if so.